# how to get a variable then a string without a space in python

Tags: python-3.x, random, while-loop

So I made this and it works, but I'm kinda picky so I want it to work 100%. This is the code

```
import random
input_1 = str(input("Do you want to roll a dice? Enter y for yes anything else for no. "))
if input_1 == "y":
    dicesides = int(input("How many sides do you want your dice to have? "))
    diceroll = random.randint(1, dicesides)
    print("The dice rolled a",diceroll ".")
    input_2 = str(input("Do you want to roll the dice again? Same keys. "))
    while input_2 == "y":
        print(random.randint(1, dicesides))
        input_2 = str(input("Do you want to roll the dice again? Same keys. "))
    else:
        print("Okay, goodbye now.")

else:
    print("Okay, goodbye now.")
```

When the code runs it tells me the number it "rolled", but it puts a space after the number.  I don't want this behavior.
After I find out how I'll change the second+ dice roll to it.

Figured it out, but thanks!

Comment: `print("The dice rolled a",diceroll ".")` is invalid syntax. I think you want `print("The dice rolled a {}.".format(diceroll))`

Answer (score 1):

Check out the help page for the `print` function.  If it's given a list of arguments, it prints them separated by the value of the `sep` argument, which is a single space by default.  So:

```
print("This",1,"is",2,"spaced",3,"out.")
print("This",1,"is",2,"not.",sep="")
```

will behave differently.  You'll want to use `sep=""` and add your own trailing or leading spaces manually to your strings, like this:

```
print("You rolled a ", roll, ".", sep="")
```